# countdown timer with number reduction after set point?

Tags: javascript

I've got a working countdown timer which starts at 30 minutes.

With only 3 minutes left (so after 27 minutes) I'd like the number 250 to decrease at random intervals from 3 minutes left down to the end of the countdown.

Any ideas?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWoGrb

```js
// Stopwatch
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var thirtyMinutes = 60 * 30,
    display = document.querySelector('#stopwatch');
    startTimer(thirtyMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<div id='stopwatch'></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what should happen to the number 250?  I imagine you want it == 0 when the countdown is up, but you didn't mention that.  How many times should it decrease?  Does it have to decrease by the same amount each time it decreases?

Comment: Hi James, with 3 minutes left ideally the 250 will decrease randomly down but no more than by 10 at random intervals.

So for e.g. 250 down to 244 after 3 seconds then 244 down to 240 after 5 seconds then 240 down to 233 after 2 seconds etc.

If that is too complicated 250 down by 3-5 would be fine as long as it's a random intervals.

And yes it should reach 0 at the end.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something like this (I hope I clearly understood the question):

Just using a if/else within the condition something to say: Go normal when more than 60*3, and when under 60*3 seconds rest, there is chance to do nothing

```js
// Stopwatch
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        if(timer > 60*3 || Math.random() < 0.25) {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            if (--timer < 0) {
                timer = duration;
            }
        } else {
          /* do not reduce the timer to wait 1 interval more */
          /* or maybe do like `timer -= Math.random()` if you want to reduce it faster */
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var thirtyMinutes = 60 * /*30*/ 4, // just set to 4 to see faster
    display = document.querySelector('#stopwatch');
    startTimer(thirtyMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<div id='stopwatch'></div>
```